# Javascript alert não está funcionando

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, tenho um formulário de cadastro aonde a senha deve se repetir, e todos os campos devem ser preenchidos, caso contrário, o usuário permanecerá na página para realizar o cadastro. Porém, o Javascript não está funcionando ! Nem mesmo a janela aparece na tela... Existe algo que possa ser feito para arrumar ? Ou uma maneira de fazer em PHP? Porque o Javascript não funciona?

Eis o código:

cadastra_usuario.php

```
<?php 
    include('conecta.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('function_usuario.php');

    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $cadastra = cadastraUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $senha);

    if($senha != $senha2){
        ?><script>
        alert("As senhas não conferem!");
        window.location.href="cadastro.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    if($cadastra == null){
        ?><script>
        alert("Por favor, preencha todos os campos!");
        windows.location.href="cadastro.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    } else {
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

cadastro.php

```
<?php 
    include ('function_usuario.php');
?>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="pt-br"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>New Cars</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,800,700,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iconfonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container-twelve">
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
            <h1 class="titles">Cadastro</h1>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) {?>
                <p><?= $_SESSION["success"] ?></p>
            <?php }?>
            <?php unset($_SESSION["success"]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four" id ="login">
            <form action="cadastra_usuario.php"  method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                <label for="email">Email de usuário </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Seu email para login">
                <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Sua senha">
                <label for="senha2">Repita sua senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha2" placeholder="Repita sua senha">
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
            </form>

            <p><a href="index.php"> << Voltar para o site</a></p>
            <p><a href="login.php"> Já tenho um cadastro >> </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ao inves de abrir e fechar as tags `<?php ?>` apenas dê um `echo "<script> alert('Por favor, preencha todos os campos!'); windows.location.href='cadastro.php'; </script>";`, tente ai e vê se da certo.

Comment: Como disse o Bacco, esse seu HTML não é válido. O script não está dentro do `<head>` ou `<body>`. Veja o código fonte do seu HTML gerado. Jogue essa if's para baixo ou use uma flag.

Comment: Ou simplesmente guarde as mensagens em uma variável, e mostre numa DIV em destaque no corpo do próprio form, que fica melhor em todos os sentidos. Inclusive fica mais amigável.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um problema da sua solução é que você quer ao mesmo tempo usar um alert e redirecionar o usuário para outra página.

Fica uma sugestão para resolver os problemas: guarde as mensagens e envie de volta para o formulário, caso ocorra algum erro. Assim, o erro aparecerá no próprio `form` de cadastro.

Veja o código otimizado:

```
<?php 
    include('conecta.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('function_usuario.php');

    $senha  = $_POST['senha'];
    $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];
    $nome   = $_POST['nome'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];

    if($senha != $senha2){
        $erro = urlencode( 'As senhas não conferem!' );
        header("Location: http://example.com/cadastro.php?erro=$erro");
        die();
    }

    $cadastra = cadastraUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $senha);
    if( $cadastra == null){
        $erro = urlencode( 'Por favor, preencha todos os campos!' );
        header("Location: http://example.com/cadastro.php?erro=$erro");
        die();
    }

    $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
    header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

E no cadastro.php coloque o trecho PHP para mostrar o erro:

```
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four" id ="login">
            <?php if( isset( $_GET['erro'] ) ) {
                echo '<div class="erro">';
                echo htmlentities( $_GET['erro'] );
                echo "</div>\n";
            } ?>
            <form action="cadastra_usuario.php"  method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
```

Comment: Isso funcionou pro caso das senhas não conferirem, mas por algum motivo, não funcionou para o caso do formulário ficar em branco... porque será ?

Comment: Bom, aí já nao dá pra saber, pois vc não pos o código que testa se o formulário está em branco. Provavelmente, olhando pro seu código, se existir tal código, ele fica em "cadastraUsuario". Se lá não é feita a conferência, aí tem que implementar.

Comment: O simples fato de usar o $cadastra = null ja nao testa se o formulario esta em branco ?

Comment: Depende do que tem na função cadastraUsuario. Se a função testa se tá em branco e devolve null, sim. Senão, não.

Comment: Obrigado, agora compreendi !

Answer (score -4):

Precisa incluir o echo

ex.:  echo '
alert("As senhas não conferem!");
window.location.href="cadastro.php";
';

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).